# Why PlayerPrefs not working although I use "HasKey" and Save() on android?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know others have written this problem before but even if I use haskey or save my android device does not save data. its work fine on pc btw.

```
 public class PlayerData : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float HighScore { get; set; }
   
 }
```

other script for save and load

```
public class PlayerPersistence : MonoBehaviour
 {
    
     public static void SavePlayerHighScore(float highScore)
     {
         if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
         {
             Debug.Log("has key");
         }
         else
         {
             PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", highScore);
             PlayerPrefs.Save();
         }
         
 
     }
 
     public static PlayerData LoadData()
     {
        
         float highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0);
         PlayerPrefs.Save();
         PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData()
         {
            
             HighScore = highScore
         };
         return playerData;
     }
 }
```

and calling like this

```
 public PlayerData playerData { get; private set; }
 
   private void Awake()
     {
         playerData = PlayerPersistence.LoadData();
         HighScore();
         t.text = playerData.HighScore.ToString();
     }
```

EDIT: timer is score actually if is less than highScore(saved data) is changing the new one with old data and this is how i calling the class

```
public PlayerData playerData { get; private set; }

private void Awake()
    {
      
        playerData = PlayerPersistence.LoadData();
        
    }
 
if(finish){
  if (timer < playerData.HighScore)
            {
                PlayerPersistence.SavePlayerHighScore(timer); // last score;
                playerData = PlayerPersistence.LoadData();
                bestTime.text = "Best Time: " + playerData.HighScore.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                bestTime.text = "Best Time: " + playerData.HighScore.ToString();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: If you classes a pure data containers without needing to be attached to a GameObject they should not be `MonoBehaviour`! In particular it is **forbidden** in Unity to use `new` for `MonoBehaviour`. (See e.g. [Why am I getting a warning: You are trying to create a "MonoBehaviour" using the "new" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015651/im-getting-the-warning-you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-using-the-new))

It should be

```
// Use Serializable and fields instead of properties
// So you can actually see the values in the Unity inspector!
[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public float HighScore;
}
```

and

```
// This class can even be static since it only contains static members 
// and never needs/means to be instantiated
public static class PlayerPersistence
{
    ...    
}
```

---

Then why do you only save a new Highscore if there was never a Highscore so far? Wouldn't you rather want to check if the new Highscore is higher and then overwrite an existing one? Also using `PlayerPrefs.Save` after `GetInt` is pretty unnecessary ;)

```
public static class PlayerPersistence
{
    // Optional parameter: if you don't pass it in it will always assume false by default
    public static void SavePlayerHighScore(float highScore, bool forceOverwrite = false)
    {
        if (!forceOverwrite && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
        {
            Debug.Log("has key -> check if higher");
            var currentScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore");
            if(currentScore >= highScore)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Current HighScore is higher -> will not overwrite");
                return;
            }
         }     
         
         Debug.Log("Saving new Highscore");
         PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", highScore);
         PlayerPrefs.Save();
     }
 
     public static PlayerData LoadData()
     {
         var highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0);

         PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData()
         {  
             HighScore = highScore
         };

         return playerData;
     }
 }
```

And finally it should be

```
[SerializeField] private PlayerData _playerData;

public PlayerData PlayerData => _playerData;

private void Awake()
{
    _playerData = PlayerPersistence.LoadData();

    HighScore();
    t.text = _playerData.HighScore.ToString();
}
```

Now it still depends of course on how exactly you call `SavePlayerHighScore` which you didn't show us.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to show how im calling it. i`ll edit it

Comment: I tried and fixed what did you said but still not working best score is always 0. Could it be related to the device I am using?